# Branch points of $f(z)= \frac{\sqrt{z} \log(z)}{(1+z)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, branch-points

How does one go about finding the branch points/holomorphic branches of a multi-function composed of several other multi-functions? Here is an example of what I mean:

> Let $f(z)= [\frac{\sqrt{z} \log(z)}{(1+z)^2}]$ be a multifunction. Identify the branch points and find a holomorphic branch.

I have no idea how to approach this if $\sqrt{z}$ and $\log(z)$ are considered multi-functions themselves. Can someone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: I like the question.  I guess: since $\sqrt{z} = e^{(\log z)/2}$, the whole thing has only the branch behavior of $\log z$.

Comment: @GEdgar So everything comes down to a choice of branch of $\log(z)$?

Comment: Another way to say it:  $\sqrt{z}$ is single-valued on the Riemann surface of $\log z$.  But I await an actual answer from someone who knows more about this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have two multi-valued functions $\sqrt{z}$ and $\log{z}$ to consider when looking for branch points of
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\sqrt{z}\log{z}}{(1+z)^2}\tag{1}
  \end{align*}

We start by looking at each of the functions separately to recall the base information. At first the simpler one:

> **Branch points of $\sqrt{z}$:**

Since $\sqrt{z}$ is the inverse of the function $z^2$ we expect $w(z)=\sqrt{z}$ having two values. To analyse the multivaluedness it is convenient to use polar coordinates and we write $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta=\theta_{p}+2\pi n$ and $0\leq \theta_{p}<2\pi, n\in\mathbb{Z}$. We then have
\begin{align*}
  w=r^{1/2} e^{i\theta_{p}/2}e^{n\pi i}\tag{2}
  \end{align*}
where $r^{1/2}=\sqrt{r}\geq 0$ and $n$ is an integer. For a given value of $z$, the function $w(z)=\sqrt{z}$ takes two possible values corresponding to $n$ even and $n$ odd, namely
\begin{align*}
  \sqrt{r}e^{i\theta_{p}/2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \sqrt{r}e^{i\theta_{p}/2}e^{\pi i}=-\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta_{p}/2}
  \end{align*}

- The key observation here is, when traversing a small circuit around $z=0$, we do not return to the original value. When starting for instance at $z=\varepsilon$ for real $\varepsilon >0$ and letting $n=0$ we start with $\theta_p=0$ and after returning to $z=\varepsilon, \theta_p=2\pi$ we have according to (2) $w=\sqrt{\varepsilon}e^{2i\pi/2}=-\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. Traversing another circuit we have $w=\sqrt{\varepsilon}e^{4i\pi/2}=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$ and this continues for $n$ even and $n$ odd.

  Since a point is a *branch point* of a function $w(z)$ iff it is discontinuous upon traversing a small circuit around this point, we have $0$ identified as branch point of the function $w(z)=\sqrt{z}$.
- The point at $z=\infty$ is another branch point of $\sqrt{z}$ which can be seen as follows. We consider $z=\frac{1}{t}$ and note that $0$ is a branch point of $t^{-1/2}$ which can be argued in the same we as we did above for $z^{1/2}$.
- If we take a closed circuit that does *not* enclose $z=0$ then the phase $\theta_p$ varies continuously between two values $0\leq \theta_1\leq \theta_p\leq \theta_2<2\pi$ as $z$ traverses the circuit returning exactly to its previous value with no phase change.

[image]

We are now in the situation to restrict $w$ to an open region of the plane so that the resulting function is single-valued and continuous. One way to do so is by taking $n=0$ and restricting the region by cutting out the real positive axis and by also deleting $z=0$ and $z=\infty$. The semiaxis $\Re z>0$ is called the *branch cut*.

> **Branch points of $\log{z}$:**

Since $\log{z}$ is the inverse of the function $e^z$ which has period $2\pi i$ we expect $w(z)=\log{z}$ having countably infinite values. We use polar coordinates and write $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta=\theta_{p}+2\pi n$ and $0\leq \theta_{p}<2\pi, n\in\mathbb{Z}$. We then have
\begin{align*}
  w=\log{r} + i\theta_{p}+2n\pi i\tag{3}
  \end{align*}
where $\log r> 0$ and $n$ is an integer. For a given value of $z$, the function $w(z)=\log{z}$ takes infinite values corresponding to $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

- Again, when traversing a small circuit around $z=0$, we do not return to the original value. When starting for instance at $z=\varepsilon$ for real $\varepsilon >0$ and letting $n=0$ we start with $\theta_p=0$ and after returning to $z=\varepsilon, \theta_p=2\pi$ we have according to (3) $w=\log{r} + i\theta_{p}+2\pi i$. Traversing another circuit we have $w=\log{r} + i\theta_{p}+4\pi i$ and this continues for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

  So, we have $0$ identified as branch point of the function $w(z)=\log{z}$.
- The point at $z=\infty$ is another branch point of $\log{z}$ which can be seen as follows. We consider $z=\frac{1}{t}$ and note that $0$ is a branch point of $\log{\frac{1}{t}}=-\log{t}$ which can be argued in the same way as we did above for $\log{z}$.
- If we take a closed circuit that does *not* enclose $z=0$ then the phase $\theta_p$ varies continuously between two values $0\leq \theta_1\leq \theta_p\leq \theta_2<2\pi$ as $z$ traverses the circuit returning exactly to its previous value with no phase change.

We are now in a similar situation as with $w=\sqrt{z}$. We have two branch points and can use the same branch cut $\{z|z>0\}$ to restrict $w(z)=\log{z}$ to an open region where $w$ is single-valued and continuous. We might also have cut out the real *negative* axis with phase angle $\theta_p$ in $(-\pi,\pi]$ and obtain this way the *[principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Branches_of_the_complex_logarithm)* of the logarithm.

> **Branch points of $\frac{\sqrt{z}\log{z}}{(1+z)^2}$:**

We can proceed similarly as we did above. At first we note that it is sufficient to consider $w(z)=\sqrt{z}\log{z}$ since $\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1\}$ and single-valued. In order to analyse the multivaluedness of $w(z)$ we write $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta=\theta_{p}+2\pi n$ and $0\leq \theta_{p}<2\pi, n\in\mathbb{Z}$. We then have
\begin{align*}
  w=r^{1/2} e^{i\theta_{p}/2}e^{n\pi i}(\log{r} + i\theta_{p}+2n\pi i)\tag{4}
  \end{align*}
where $r\geq 0$ and $n$ is an integer. We will see for a given value of $z$, the function $w(z)=\sqrt{z}\log{z}$ takes infinite values corresponding to $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

- Indeed, when traversing a small circuit around $z=0$, we do not return to the original value. When starting for instance at $z=\varepsilon$ for real $\varepsilon >0$ and letting $n=0$ we start with $\theta_p=0$ and after returning to $z=\varepsilon, \theta_p=2\pi$ we have according to (4) $w=\sqrt{\varepsilon}e^{2i\pi/2}\left(\log{r} + 2\pi i\right)=-\sqrt{\varepsilon}\left(\log{r} + 2\pi i\right)$. Traversing another circuit we have $w=\sqrt{\varepsilon}\left(\log{r} + 4\pi i\right)$ and this continues for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ changing the sign for $n$ even and $n$ odd.

  Again, we have $0$ identified as branch point of the function $w(z)=\sqrt{z}\log{z}$.
- The point at $z=\infty$ is another branch point of $\sqrt{z}\log{z}$ which can be seen as above by substituting    $z=\frac{1}{t}$ and  considering   $t$ close by $0$ which can be argued in the same way as we did above.
- If we take a closed circuit that does *not* enclose $z=0$ then the phase $\theta_p$ varies continuously between two values $0\leq \theta_1\leq \theta_p\leq \theta_2<2\pi$ as $z$ traverses the circuit returning exactly to its previous value with no phase change.

We are now in a similar situation as with the functions $\sqrt{z}$ and $\log{z}$. We have two branch points $z=0$ and $z=\infty$ and can use the same branch cut $\{z|z>0\}$ to restrict $w(z)=\sqrt{z}\log{z}$ to an open region where $w$ is single-valued and continuous.

**Note:** This answer follows closely section: 2.2 *Multivalued functions* from *[Complex Variables: Introduction and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521534291)* by M.J. Ablowitz and A.S. Fokas.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user: You're welcome. Thanks a lot for accepting the answer and granting the bounty. :-)